# Where is this IPv6 address coming from?

Tags: ipv6, freebsd, ifconfig

When I run ifconfig (after rebooting) on my FreeBSD 8.4 system it outputs this:

```
      inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe10:7e84%em0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
      inet6 xxxx:xxxx:1009::2 prefixlen 64
      inet6 xxxx:xxxx:1009::106 prefixlen 64
      inet6 xxxx:xxxx:1009::107 prefixlen 64
```

In my rc.conf I have these lines to configure ipv6:

```
      ipv6_defaultrouter="xxxx:xxxx:1009::1"
      ipv6_ifconfig_em0="xxxx:xxxx:1009::2"
      ipv6_ifconfig_em0_alias0="xxxx:xxxx:1009::106"
```

I do not understand where the first line of the output is coming from. fe80::225:90ff:fe10:7e84% is not an IP that I know. Could someone explain this to me?

Ps, I placed the x's to hide my real IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [link local address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses), used to exchange traffic with other machines on the same local network. Each [IPv6 Ethernet interface assigns itself a link local address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6) based on its hardware address.

> Unlike IPv4, IPv6 requires a link-local address to be assigned to every network interface on which the IPv6 protocol is enabled, even when one or more routable addresses are also assigned. Consequently, IPv6 hosts usually have more than one IPv6 address assigned to each of their IPv6-enabled network interfaces. The link-local address is required for IPv6 sublayer operations of the Neighbor Discovery Protocol, as well as for some other IPv6-based protocols, like DHCPv6. -- *Wikipedia*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will study the subject a bit better, in manuals how to configure IPv6, this just is not mentioned.